# Android Wear notification won't show up

Tags: android, android-notifications, wear-os

I'm trying to use `Pages` and `Stacks` from the `Android Wear SDK` preview. Without the `Wear` code the notifications show up fine, while if I use `Wear` specific code I can't get a notification, neither on the phone nor on the `Wear Emulator`. I've gone throught the code 10 times, I think I need a fresh pair of eyes to catch the error.

This code should create, on the phone, a `Notification` for each `Tracker` (an external device sending a `Message`) with a list of unread `Message`s (using the `InboxStyle`). On `Wear` it should stack multiple `Notification`s grouped by `Tracker`, adding a `Page` for each unread `Message`.

```
  public static void showNewMessagesNotif(Context context, Tracker tracker, List<Message> messages) {
    String trackerName = tracker.getName() + " - " + tracker.getPhoneNumber();
    String contentTitle = context.getResources().getQuantityString(R.plurals.notif_new_messages, messages.size(), messages.size());


    Intent callIntent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_CALL);
    callIntent.setData(Uri.parse("tel:" + tracker.getPhoneNumber()));
    PendingIntent callPendingIntent = PendingIntent.getActivity(context, 0, callIntent, 0);


    NotificationCompat.Builder mBuilder = new NotificationCompat.Builder(context)
            .setSmallIcon(R.drawable.ic_action_location_searching)
            .setContentTitle(contentTitle)
            .setContentText(trackerName)
            .setAutoCancel(true)
            .addAction(R.drawable.ic_action_call, context.getString(R.string.action_call), callPendingIntent);
    NotificationCompat.InboxStyle inboxStyle =
            new NotificationCompat.InboxStyle();
    // Sets a title for the Inbox style big view
    inboxStyle.setBigContentTitle(contentTitle);

    // Moves events into the big view
    for (Message message : messages) {
        inboxStyle.addLine(message.getText());
    }
    inboxStyle.setSummaryText(trackerName);
    // Moves the big view style object into the notification object.
    mBuilder.setStyle(inboxStyle);

    mBuilder.setContentIntent(getNotificationIntent(context, tracker));
    // Issue the notification here.
    NotificationManagerCompat notificationManager =
            NotificationManagerCompat.from(context);

    int notifId = (int) (NEW_MESSAGE_NOTIF_BASE_ID + tracker.getRowId());

//Android Wear Notifications
    List<Notification> wearPages = new ArrayList<Notification>();

    for (Message message : messages) {
        NotificationCompat.BigTextStyle extraPageStyle = new NotificationCompat.BigTextStyle();
        extraPageStyle.setBigContentTitle(message.getText())
                .bigText(message.getAddress());
        Notification extraPageNotification = new NotificationCompat.Builder(context)
                .setStyle(extraPageStyle)
                .build();


        wearPages.add(extraPageNotification);
    }


    WearableNotifications.Builder wearNotificationBuilder =
            new WearableNotifications.Builder(mBuilder)
                    .setHintHideIcon(true)
                    .setGroup(GROUP_BY_TRACKER).addPages(wearPages);


    // mId allows you to update the notification later on.
    notificationManager.notify(notifId, wearNotificationBuilder.build());
}
```

Comment: You seem to conflating pages and stacks - they are two completely different, separate concepts (pages are additional information attached to a single notification while stacks are groups of notifications) - which do you actually want?

Comment: Ad I said, a stack of notifications, one for each tracker. Each notification should then have multiple pages. Isn't this possible? Where does it say so?

Comment: Yes, using both stacks and pages works fine together. What you've described makes sense (showing a single summary `InboxStyle` on your phone and a stack of individual notifications on Wear), but your code only shows adding pages and not building the individual notifications and summary notification required for building a stack.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For [stacking notifications](http://developer.android.com/wear/notifications/stacks.html), you create and `notify` multiple notifications

- For each stacked notification that you want to appear on Wear, `notify` a notification where you've called `setGroup(trackerGroupId)`
- For the summary notification that you want to appear on the phone/tablet, `notify` a notification where you've called `setGroup(trackerGroupid, WearableNotifications.GROUP_ORDER_SUMMARY)`

I think your problem is that you **must** have a summary notification for any notifications to appear on either device.

Comment: The missing order was the problem. Thanks.